# SQS Client Validation Exception - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to validate an AWS S3 queue: with the following params:
Access key, Secret key, Queue URL

```
public bool ValidateSqs(string queue_url, string access_key, string secret_key)
{

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(access_key)
               || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secret_key)
               || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queue_url))
                return false;

            try
            {
                SqsClient sqsValid = new SqsClient(access_key, secret_key, queue_url);
                return sqsValid.CheckAwsCredentials();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtils.Error("fail to validate SQS", ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

here is the SqsClient:

```
public class SqsClient
{
    private AmazonSQSClient _awsSQSClient;
    private readonly int MaxRetryAttempts = 3;

    public SqsClient(string accessKey, string secretKey, string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("accessKey");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(secretKey))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("secretKey");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        }

        AccessKey = accessKey;
        SecretKey = secretKey;
        Url = url;

        try
        {
            RestartClient();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogUtils.WithParameters()
                .Append(x => AccessKey)
                .Append(x => SecretKey)
                .Error("Failed to create SQS Client", ex);

            throw;
        }
    }

 public bool CheckAwsCredentials()
        {
            try
            {
               _awsSQSClient.GetQueueAttributes(new GetQueueAttributesRequest
                {
                    QueueUrl = Url,
                    AttributeNames = new List<string> { "All" }
                });

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtils.Error(ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The exception is thrown from the CheckAwsCredentials() method.

> Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException: The request signature we calculated
>   does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret
>   Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for
>   details.
>
> The Canonical String for this request should have been 'POST
>   /49512474474/DEXQueue
>
> content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
>   host:sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
>   user-agent:aws-sdk-dotnet-45/3.3.2.4 aws-sdk-dotnet-core/3.3.8.1
>   .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0
>   OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_10.0.14393.0 ClientSync
>   x-amz-content-sha256:92f6fc97d2a609de283521acc0f05e5fabe54f4afe7427217ef2fc5521
>   x-amz-date:20170620T072209Z
>
> content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
>   92f6fc97d2a609d5e283521acc0bbccf05e5fabe54f4afe7427217ef2fc5521'

What could be the reason for the error?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The most likely cause is that value of `secretKey` is incorrect due to a copying error.

Comment: Found it!.
I had an escaping method that converted the char '+' to ' ' in my secret key!.
Thanks @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Took me a while to figure out it was due to a `/` character in the `secretKey`. Thanks to this post I tried setting a new key (without symbols) and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

This can happen due to a few reasons, including:

- Secret Key copy/paste error
- Secret Key mangling error (string escaping gone wrong)
- Accidentally using the QueueURL as the ServiceURL

Comment: I face the same issue, in my case I put Queue Url as Service Url.

for example in SQS service: Service usl does not contain queue details